# Hard disk size increased from Vmware manage dialogue but guest fedora says no storage left

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation, fedora-21

1. I created earlier a guest with 20 GB HDD size and installed fedora on it.
2. Later as it said ran out of storage, I increased the disk size from vmware dialogue to 40 GB.
3. And then increased the partition size from gparted[inside guest] to 40 GB.  Then restarted the guest.

Still the guest fedora keeps popping up a message 0 storage left on root filesystem and keeps me logging out. I checked Gparted again it shows the free storage left as 20 GB. I'm little confused here. Why is this happening?
Output of df -i

```
[ ~ ]  $ df -i
Filesystem               Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root 1146880 449290 697590   40% /
devtmpfs                 252608    395 252213    1% /dev
tmpfs                    255278      8 255270    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    255278    526 254752    1% /run
tmpfs                    255278     15 255263    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                    255278     24 255254    1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                128016    429 127587    1% /boot
/dev/sr0                      0      0      0     - /run/media/mahesh/Fedora-Live-WS-x86_64-21-5
tmpfs                    255278     44 255234    1% /run/user/1000

[ ~ ]  $ df -m
Filesystem              1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root     17479 16564         5 100% /
devtmpfs                      987     0       987   0% /dev
tmpfs                         998     1       998   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         998     1       997   1% /run
tmpfs                         998     0       998   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                         998     1       998   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                     477   156       292  35% /boot
/dev/sr0                     1404  1404         0 100% /run/media/mahesh /Fedora-Live-WS-x86_64-21-5
tmpfs                         200     1       200   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                         200     1       200   1% /run/user/42
```

Comment: Did you resize the filesystem as well?

Comment: yes using Gparted.

Comment: Post the output of: df -i and df -m.

Comment: @EEAA I added it

Comment: @EEAA is this what you asked for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have an LVM, not just normal partitions. Then you need to increase size of LVM partition as well. See this question for possible solution: https://serverfault.com/q/424678/118677

Comment: Thanks so much. I did extend it. But forgot to resize it.

Comment: You are welcome, I have partly stolen the answer points from EEAA, because without df output it was not possible to guess it so easy;)